# Are question about outdoor organizations on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about outdoor organizations and organizations which activity is primarily outdoor related on topic?

For example, questions about membership criteria, badges and titles requirements, outdoor activities, history of organizations like polish PTTK, scouting/pathfinding groups?

Comment: Aren't the answer to these likely to simply be a link to that organisations web site?

Comment: @Liam not always, even the organization doesn't need to have a web site